# Java, MongoDB - Embedded document with REST

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest

I'm building a REST service in Java by using MongoDB (`mongodb-java-driver`), Jersey, and Jackson.
An example of the classes I'm using is the following: Employee

```
public class Employee extends BasicDBObject {
    public Employee() {}
    public Employee(String name, Company company) {
        put("name", name);
        put("company", company);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return get("name").toString();
    }
    public Company getCompany() {
        return (Company) get("company");
    }
    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        put("company", company);
    }
}
```

Company

```
public class Company extends BasicDBObject {
    public Company() {}
    public Company(String name, String city) {
        put("name", name);
        put("city", city);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return get("name").toString();
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return get("city").toString();
    }
}
```

and the REST service

```
public class EmployeeRestSrv {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createEmployee(Employee employee) {
        DBCollection employeesCollection = DataSource.getDbCollection("employees");
        employeesCollection.setObjectClass(Employee.class);
        // employee.company.name ?
        employeesCollection.insert(employee);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

DataSource is the class that actually creates a connection with MongoDB.

If I send this JSON object with a POST

```
{
    "employee" : "foo",
    "company" : {
        "name" : "foocompany",
        "city" : "san francisco"
    }
}
```

I correctly get the document in `employeesCollection`.

My question is: when in `createEmployee` at commented line, how can I access the embedded object's fields (`Company`)? I also tried `employee.get("company").get("name")` with no effect.

The final goal is to "force" a sort of One-to-Many relationship and I'd like to be able to store in company document also the list of employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since BasicDBObject is basically a Map, I implemented this walk-around in Employee class, to obtain the Company structure:

```
...
public Company getCompany() {
    try {
        return new Company((Map) get("company"));
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setCompany(Company c) {
    put("company", c);
}
...
```

Of course I also created a new constructor in Company, in order to accept Map:

```
public Company(Map m) {
    super(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `employee.get("company.name")`

That should also work for updating nested documents.

As far as relationships are concerned, this would work as you are storing one-to-many relationships as nested objects.

Comment: This gives me a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `employee.getCompany().getName();`
When you say your code "had no effect", what do you mean?
(Also, you meant `createEmployee`, not `createUser`, right?)

Comment: Yes, sorry... Edited!
With "no effect" I mean that I can't get what I'm looking for; the code `employee.get("company").get("name")` actually doesn't work since it says `cannot find symbol method get(java.lang.String)` for `java.lang.Object` class... Unfortunately, `employee.getCompany().getName()` gives me the same error; thanks anyway!